# Incomplete Stack Trace in NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm implementing NLog in an app. The config for the DB Insert that the log does includes this ...

```
<parameter layout="${stacktrace:format=Raw}" name="@Stacktrace"/>
```

yet when a log item is written, the output always looks something like this...

> MethodName1 at offset 85 in file:line:column :0:0
>
> MethodName2 at offset 93 in file:line:column :0:0
>
> MethodName3 at offset 160 in file:line:column :0:0

Can anyone suggest why the filenames and location details are missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want NLog to show filenames and line numbers, make sure to set **Generate debug info** to **Full** or **pdb-only** in the [Advanced Compiler Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07bysfz2(v=vs.110).aspx) dialog.

Comment: I've checked and _all_ of the projects in the solution are set to *Full*, so it's not that.

Comment: When does the problem occur? While debugging, when published or both?

Comment: Debugging. I've not got anywhere close to publishing the code yet! :-)

Comment: Can you see the .pdb files in your bin\debug folder? If so, I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: Yes, they are all there. :-( Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I tend to clear my bin\debug (or release) whenever NLog is messing with me. Then build and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `${stacktrace}` ever contain any useful information?   For example, assuming a very simple program, the stack trace would look like something like this just before the `StackTraceLayoutRenderer` did it's thing.

```
logEvent.StackTrace.GetFrames()
{System.Diagnostics.StackFrame[14]}
    [0]: {Write at offset 263 in file:line:column c:\Dev\NLogSrc\src\NLog\LoggerImpl.cs:76:17    }
    [1]: {WriteToTargets at offset 161 in file:line:column c:\Dev\NLogSrc\src\NLog\Logger.cs:542:13    }
    [2]: {Debug at offset 103 in file:line:column c:\Dev\NLogSrc\src\NLog\Logger1.cs:454:17    }
    [3]: {Build at offset 232 in file:line:column c:\Dev\NLogSrc\src\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:43:17    }
    [4]: {GetAnother at offset 77 in file:line:column c:\Dev\NLogSrc\src\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:25:17    }
    [5]: {Main at offset 85 in file:line:column c:\Dev\NLogSrc\src\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:16:13    }
    [6]: {_nExecuteAssembly at offset 0 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0    }
    [7]: {ExecuteAssembly at offset 107 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0    }
    [8]: {RunUsersAssembly at offset 40 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0    }
    [9]: {ThreadStart_Context at offset 112 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0    }
    [10]: {RunInternal at offset 180 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0    }
    [11]: {Run at offset 22 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0 }
    [12]: {Run at offset 65 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0 }   
    [13]: {ThreadStart at offset 68 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0    }
```

If you looked at items 5 (my code) and 6 (runtime(?)), there's quite a bit of difference

[image]

This renderer defaults to the first item in the stack that didn't originate with NLog (#3) and the `TopFrames` configuration item defaults to 3, so I would expect your first line to have some information of value, whereas the others may or may not.

It might be worth setting a breakpoint just before your logging call and try `new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrames()` in your immediate window to see what values are there vs what you are seeing.

Comment: Odd, I'm not getting anything in VS either ...`
     [0]: {Get at offset 125 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
     [1]: {Get at offset 204 in file:line:column D:\Repos\ePin\ePin.Infrastructure\BusinessLogic\CrudUowBase.cs:42:13
     [2]: {Get at offset 172 in file:line:column D:\Repos\ePin\ePin.Infrastructure\Services\ServiceBase.cs:50:13
     [3]: {SyncInvokeGet at offset 223 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
     [4]: {Invoke at offset 1223 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
     [5]: {InvokeBegin at offset 623 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0`

Comment: At least not except for a couple of lines.

Comment: By changing my layout to use format=Flat and setting the number of frames I'm getting information I can use, although nothing I do will force NLog to include the filename and line:column of the statement. Thanks @Joe for the pointer to at least getting me _something_